# Not able to access shared outlook inbox via python

Tags: python, outlook, exchange-server, office-automation

I am using Outlook application locally as well. One is my personal mail id which is logged in. And another one is a Outlook shared email/inbox.

With the code snippet below, I was trying to fetch both mail ids. But failed to do it. It gives me the first one only.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

for account in mapi.Accounts:
    print(account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
```

Comment: Does Outlook actually show the other mailbox in the folder treeview?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the [Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store) objects in the current profile.

Then you can get the [Store.DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.displayname) property which returns a string representing the display name of the `Store` object.